# how to apply if else in a group by query PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a view on the basis of three column values

1. `config->>'camera_http_port'`
2. `config->>'external_host'`
3. `config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'`

The whole view query seems like this

```
create or replace view duplicated_cameras_report as
(select
    count(nullif(c.is_online = false, true)) as online,
    c.config->>'camera_http_port' as camera_http_port,
    c.config->>'external_host' as external_host,
    LOWER(config->'snapshots'->>'jpg') as jpg,
    count(nullif(cr.status like 'off', 'on')) as is_recording,
    count(*) as count
from
    cameras c
left join cloud_recordings cr
    on c.id = cr.camera_id
group by camera_http_port, external_host, jpg
having
    count(*) > 1)
```

We have added a new column in table cameras which is `recording_from_nvr` boolean.

also new config as `config->'snapshots'->>'nvr_jpg'` and `config->>'nvr_http_port'`

I want to generate the same view but for all those rows where `recording_from_nvr` is true, I want to group by `config->'snapshots'->>'nvr_jpg'` instead of `config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'` and `config->>'nvr_http_port'` instead of `config->>'camera_http_port'`

and where `recording_from_nvr` is false, then group by `config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'` and `config->>'camera_http_port'`.

I don't know if that's possible or not. Please guide me in case this can be done in some other way, the purpose of the view is to eliminate those cameras where

`camera_http_port`, `external_host` and `'snapshots'->>'jpg'` are **same**

and

if `recording_from_nvr` = true, and `nvr_http_port`, `external_host` and `'snapshots'->>'nvr_jpg'` are **same**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way might be to use a `UNION` of two queries, one having `WHERE recording_from_nvr` and the other `WHERE NOT recording_from_nvr` - and different `GROUP BY` clauses, accordingly to your specs.

Example:

```
create or replace view duplicated_cameras_report as
(
-- first case, WHERE recording_from_nvr = TRUE
select
    count(nullif(c.is_online = false, true)) as online,
    c.config->>'nvr_http_port' as http_port,
    c.config->>'external_host' as external_host,
    LOWER(c.config->'snapshots'->>'nvr_jpg') as jpg
    count(nullif(cr.status like 'off', 'on')) as is_recording,
    count(*) as count
from
    cameras c
left join cloud_recordings cr
    on c.id = cr.camera_id
where c.recording_from_nvr
group by http_port, external_host, jpg
having
    count(*) > 1

UNION ALL

-- second case, WHERE recording_from_nvr = FALSE
select
    count(nullif(c.is_online = false, true)) as online,
    c.config->>'camera_http_port' as http_port,
    c.config->>'external_host' as external_host,
    LOWER(c.config->'snapshots'->>'jpg') as jpg,
    count(nullif(cr.status like 'off', 'on')) as is_recording,
    count(*) as count
from
    cameras c
left join cloud_recordings cr
    on c.id = cr.camera_id
where NOT c.recording_from_nvr
group by http_port, external_host, jpg
having
    count(*) > 1
) ;
```